# Global Slack Notifier is not found in Jenkins How to Make a use of only Slack

Tags: jenkins, slack

Global Slack Notifier is not found, They just upgrade it. Initially it was coming as -

[Global Slack Notifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yom3O.png)

After that they have upgrade to - Slack only. Like -

[Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuIAE.jpg)

Now I am not getting how to make the configuration. Where to put my --

Team Subdomain: xxdextxchxxx
Integration Token Credential ID: 
Create a secret text credential using 
**ytSTVUBdg2dererFJsrYBayDx** as the value

Any help ? --- How to make the step up. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Got it -

Workspace - YourTechSubdomainName

Then Click on add credential -

Click -> Jenkins ->

Secret (Put your secret id from Slack)
Id -> Any Random Id

Check the screen shot below

[Process to add slack id from jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7sDv.png)

[Process to add slack id from jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTC0k.png)

Once done click on add. Select credential from dropdown. Click on test. Check the below screenshot

[Slack Notification Select Credential Using Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNhNv.png)

[Test Connection Jenkins with Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joKyP.png)